# Why my android studio emulator is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

[I am trying to run my app on an android studio emulator, it says that it lunch successfully but it does not work anda small window like the image pops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUKmy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of random issue you can wipe the data from the AVD manager and relaunch your application in it. Hope it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because of several reasons, try to clean project and Rebuild project! then restart Android studio , sometimes it helps

Comment: It didn't work. I even tried to reinstall  android studio and it still doing that